# Why should I call os.Exit at most once in the main function?

Tags: go, fatal-error, deferred-execution

I started a new job and we've been instructed to use [Ubers Go coding standards](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md). I'm not sure about [one of their guidelines entitled "Exit Once"](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#exit-once):

> If possible, prefer to call `os.Exit` or `log.Fatal` at most once in your `main()`. If there are multiple error scenarios that halt program execution, put that logic under a separate function and return errors from it.

Wouldn't this just mean offloading `main()` into another function (`run()`)? This seems a little superfluous to me. What benefits does Uber's approach have?

Comment: It just means to call os.Exit just one in func main. How you do that (e.g. via run()) doesn't matter and is not important to that rule.

Comment: If you've been instructed, you should know what it means to your employer. If you've just been told, ask for instructions.

Comment: The intention of the guideline is to produce code that handles fatal errors in one place. In the example you've cited, 3 `log.Fatal` calls get replaced by a single `log.Fatal`

Comment: @Volker The rationale behind Uber's guideline is more profound than you think.

Comment: @byxor The intention isn't simply to reduce the number of calls to `log.Fatal`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Uber's entire Go coding standards, but that particular piece of advice is sound. One issue with [`os.Exit`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Exit) is that it puts an end to the programme very brutally, without honouring any deferred function calls pending:

> Exit causes the current program to exit with the given status code. Conventionally, code zero indicates success, non-zero an error.
> The program terminates immediately; **deferred functions are not run**.

(my emphasis)

However, those deferred function calls may be responsible for important cleanup tasks. Consider Uber's example code snippet:

```golang
package main

func main() {
  args := os.Args[1:]
  if len(args) != 1 {
    log.Fatal("missing file")
  }
  name := args[0]

  f, err := os.Open(name)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer f.Close()

  // If we call log.Fatal after this line,
  // f.Close will not be called.

  b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  // ...
}
```

If `ioutil.ReadAll` returns a non-nil error, `log.Fatal` is called; and because [`log.Fatal` calls `os.Exit` under the hood](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/log/log.go;l=366), the deferred call to `f.Close` will not be run. In this particular case, it's not that serious, but imagine a situation where deferred calls involved some cleanup, like removing files; you'd leave your disk in an unclean state. For more on that topic, see [episode #112 of the Go Time podcast](https://changelog.com/gotime/112#transcript-69), in which these considerations were discussed.

Therefore, it's a good idea to eschew `os.Exit`, `log.Fatal`, etc. "deep" in your programme. A `run` function as described in Uber's Go coding standards allows deferred calls to be run as they should before programme execution ends (potentially with a non-zero status code):

```golang
package main

func main() {
  if err := run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}

func run() error {
  args := os.Args[1:]
  if len(args) != 1 {
    return errors.New("missing file")
  }
  name := args[0]

  f, err := os.Open(name)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer f.Close()

  b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // ...
}
```

An additional benefit of this approach is that, although the `main` function itself isn't readily testable, you can design such a `run` function with testability in mind; see [Mat Ryer's blog post](https://pace.dev/blog/2020/02/12/why-you-shouldnt-use-func-main-in-golang-by-mat-ryer.html) on that topic.